# Puppet package provider relocatable RPM

Tags: puppet, rpm

Is it possible to pass a new root install location to an RPM via puppets package provider? I've got a relocatable package that I want to override the install location on and would rather do it via the provider than a cmd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom provider which is a wrapper of `rpm` provider. I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/puppet-users/browse_thread/thread/7074b4f6c9099fd2) by Googling.

Comment: Kind of what I figured; cheers for the helpful reply.